# A little line under the name of the part

Tags: table-of-contents

How can i make a little line under the name of the part. My trial is

`\part*{PART I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{{\huge \textbf{PART I}} \\ \hrule}`

but this falis, and here is a screenshot including the part.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Well, do you have something more to provide than this fragment?

Comment: I can't really work on this until you provide more code.

Comment: This is all i wrote sir after the command `\tableofcontents`. There is no more.

Comment: No @ChristianHupfer

Comment: Please provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). It will greatly help us to help you with your problem.

Comment: More code 


`\usepackage{tocloft} 

% to center the part name 
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfill} 
\renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfill} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 




\newpage





\part*{PART I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{{\huge \textbf{PART I}}} `

Comment: @user100256: Done.  But, now that you have seen what a MWE is, why don’t you post one yourself?  **Edit:** And may I suggest using `titlesec`/`titletoc` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don’t want to, I’ll post for you a MWE to start to work with (**edited** according to OP’s whishes):

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{tocloft} % to center the part name
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfill}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{A Title}
\addtocontents{toc}{\nobreak\smallskip\hrule}

\section{Foo bar}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

---

## Addition

It is not clear from your question whether you want a rule only under a particular part title, or below all.  In the second case, reading the documentation of the `tocloft` package, it seems to me that a simpler solution is feasible:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{tocloft} % to center the part name
\renewcommand*{\cftpartpresnum}  {\hfill}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartleader}   {\hfill}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartafterpnum}{\par\nobreak\smallskip\hrule}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{A Title}

\section{Foo bar}
Some text.

\section{Biz baz}
Some text.

\part{Another Title}

\section{Yuk yuk}\
Some text.

\section{Hu-hu?}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I want a rule only under a particular part title. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks @GustavoMezzetti, the first code is the required one. But i need to make the name of the part huge, how can I achieve that ?. Besides, is it possible to make another line above the name of the part and letting the name of the part with the two lines look like a sandwich?. Thanks in Advance