# add lines in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to add a horizontal line after the name of the part in the table of contents. I tried

```
\Part{Part I} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\noindent
{\color{blue} \rule{\linewidth}{1mm} }}
```

but unfortunately this does not work. I need help in solving such a problem. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\newpage 

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\part*{PART I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{{\huge \textbf{PART I}}}
```

Comment: And we also need help to help you. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What is the difference to your previous question? And can you give some feedback if the two possible solutions proposed in the answer work for you?

Comment: I edited the post and i added my own MWE @samcarter

Comment: Thanks! Next step, try to use the solutions proposed by @GustavoMezzetti http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324620/36296. In case they don't work for you GIVE FEEDBACK!

Comment: That said besides the missing xcolor package, your `\addtocontents{toc}{\noindent
{\color{blue} \rule{\linewidth}{1mm} }}` works with your example.

Comment: I said above that `\addtocontents{toc}{\noindent {\color{blue} \rule{\linewidth}{1mm} }}` does not work. @samcarter