# Setting the name of the part between two lines

Tags: table-of-contents, parts

In the screenshot below, I have a question: 
[image]

How can I decrease the space between the upper line and the following statement to be identical to that between the same statement and the lower line?

Here is my trial

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfill}  % to center the part name 
\renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfill}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\addtocontents{toc}{\smallskip\hrule} % for the first line 
\part*{PART I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{{\huge \textbf{PART I}}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\nobreak\smallskip\hrule} % for the second one 

\end{document}.
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your approach is strange. Is this a one-shot part header that you want to insert? Otherwise you should redefine `\part` to output the header in your particular way, with the rules and everything, in order to be sure that it will come out the same way all over your document. Also some protections against page breaks inside a header are missing.

Comment: @Dirk: It's the ToC entry, not the `part` header

Comment: If you have a solution or a clear suggestion related to that posted above just write it @Dirk

Comment: Don't use `\huge` etc in `\addcontentsline` etc. Such commands are fragile

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, it is not clear. The given source obviously does not generate the example screenshot. Maybe it's both?
HusseinEid, I do not understand what you want and cannot reproduce your result with the given source code. I am afraid I cannot make a clear suggestion while the question is still unclear.

Comment: @Dirk: I think the page number on the right rather hints to the `ToC` than the `Part` header.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, yes. But `\part` fills the `.aux` with `\contentsline`, which is used in turn to generate the ToC. So either `\part` or (probably better) `\contentsline` should be redefined for the whole document. (You seem to agree that this is not a request for a one-shot entry, but a general rule is required, right?)
Then, I also _think_ that it is quite ugly to put lines into the ToC and not the part headers and would recommend a more coherent approach (redefining both).

Comment: @Dirk: I agree that it is ugly (in ToC) ;-) The `minitoc` package yields something similar out of the box, if I remember correctly

Comment: Well, I think the question was not to have a nice, but a quick solution. Ouch!

Comment: Well, do have a different approach to customize the name of the part rather than these two ugly lines?. @Dirk

Comment: What is wrong with the solution you got in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324608/ a couple of days ago?

Comment: It didn’t seem good @Dirk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hack is to add a negative space to the first `\addtocontents`. With

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\smallskip\hrule\vspace{-4.5ex}} % for the first line 
\part*{PART I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{{\huge \textbf{PART I}}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\nobreak\smallskip\hrule} % for the second one
```

you obtain

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to increase the thickness of the two lines ? @gernot

Comment: Yes, with the `height` keyword.

Comment: Can you clear more please @Dirk .

Comment: Thanks @Dirk . I searched and i found out precisely what you mean.