# Part name between 2 hl in toc

Tags: table-of-contents

How to add 2 lines to all part names in the toc as in this image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany,french]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=21cm,paperheight=29.7cm, body={18cm,25.7cm}, top=2.5cm, left=1.5cm}
\usepackage[pdftex,pdfauthor={Moi},pdftitle={Bonjour},pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,pdfstartview={FitH},colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
{

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Preface}

\mainmatter

\part{kafhkahj}
\chapter{lafhjlahf}
\chapter{lafhsfsffasf}
\chapter{l54gfvsahf}

\part{pokjk}
\chapter{32546}

}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable tex code resulting in your shown image. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing. Imortant is the used document class and relevant packages for building the TOC.

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326183/36296 could help

Comment: @samcarter I was hoping not to include three `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}` for every part. Also the lines in that question are thin, the part name is centered, the page number is shown and it uses part* not part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with `titletoc`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany,french]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{body={18cm,25.7cm}, top=2.5cm, left=1.5cm}
\usepackage{mfirstuc, titlecaps}
\newcommand{\Partname}{Partie}%
    \usepackage{titletoc}
     \titlecontents{part}[0pt]{\bfseries\protect\addvspace{15pt}\titlerule[1pt]\addvspace{1ex}}%
    {}{\Partname~}%numbered, unnumbered
     {\hfill\contentspage}[\addvspace{0.7ex}{\titlerule[1pt]}\addvspace{1.5ex}]
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
{

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Préface}

\part{kafhkahj}
\chapter{lafhjlahf}
\chapter{lafhsfsffasf}
\chapter{l54gfvsahf}

\part{pokjk}
\chapter{32546}

}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I adjusted your code a little bit: `\usepackage{mfirstuc, titlecaps}\usepackage{titletoc}\titlecontents{part}[0pt]{\bfseries\protect\addvspace{15pt}\titlerule[1pt]\addvspace{1ex}}{}{}{\hfill\contentspage}[\addvspace{0.7ex}{\titlerule[1pt]}\addvspace{1.5ex}]`. Is there a way to "turn off" this layout for a specific part?

Comment: Yes, probably, using a boolean variable, for instance. Can you be more specific?